Sphinx Search Weight on Fields Issue
Please help with weight, no matter what i set i am getting same numbers
mysql> select id, Address_City, WEIGHT() AS scorex from `Index` where MATCH('toronto')
ORDER BY WEIGHT() DESC LIMIT 0,10;
+----------+----------------+-----------+
| id | address_city | scorex |
+----------+----------------+-----------+
| 27158132 | Port Hope | 21842.855 |
| 27347654 | Grey Highlands | 21842.855 |
| 27347655 | Grey Highlands | 21842.855 |
| 27625274 | Barrie | 21842.855 |
| 27641362 | Mayfield | 21842.855 |
| 27641811 | Barrie | 21842.855 |
| 27648523 | Barrie | 21842.855 |
| 27352629 | Toronto | 21701.098 |
| 27514967 | Toronto | 21701.098 |
| 27663731 | Toronto | 21701.098 |
+----------+----------------+-----------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)

I am expecting to give boost to rows containing city name Toronto
So i am adding field_weights, full query below
mysql> select id, Address_City, WEIGHT() AS scorex from `Index` where MATCH('toronto')
ORDER BY WEIGHT() DESC LIMIT 0,10 OPTION
field_weights=(Address_Province=1,Address_City=99, Address_StreetAddress=1);
+----------+----------------+-----------+
| id | address_city | scorex |
+----------+----------------+-----------+
| 27158132 | Port Hope | 21842.855 |
| 27347654 | Grey Highlands | 21842.855 |
| 27347655 | Grey Highlands | 21842.855 |
| 27625274 | Barrie | 21842.855 |
| 27641362 | Mayfield | 21842.855 |
| 27641811 | Barrie | 21842.855 |
| 27648523 | Barrie | 21842.855 |
| 27352629 | Toronto | 21701.098 |
| 27514967 | Toronto | 21701.098 |
| 27663731 | Toronto | 21701.098 |
+----------+----------------+-----------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)

As you can see numbers are still the same
Please explain what i am doing wrong.
Sphinx version:
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+------------------------+
| VERSION() |
+------------------------+
| 3.4.1 (commit efbcc65) |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

